# Dialogflow: How can I repeat a previous intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have an intent with slot-filling, after all parameters are set my agent then prompts the user to confirm that the parameters are correct. If the user answers "no",  a follow up intent is triggered, but I don't know how to make it so this repeats the previous intent allowing the user to correct the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a follow-up intent with yes and another follow-up intent with no values.
Then in the follow-up no values, check the user input and then again call the main intent.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Intents represent *what the user says or does* and *not* what you do with that information. So there is no way to force "repeating" the previous Intent, since the user may choose to do something else.

What you *can* do is

- Clear out the various Input Contexts, except for an Input Context that your original Intent is valid.
- Re-prompt in a way that they would answer it so the original Intent would be triggered.